# Make a list of row and column indices for arbitrary shaped matrix

Tags: python, list, indices

I am generating a matrix of subplots and need to iterate through a list of column and row values such as:

`indices = [[1,1], [1,2], [1,3], [2,1], [2,2], [2,3]]`

This would be easy to generate with a nested for loop:

```
rows=2
cols=3
indices = []
for row in range(1, rows + 1):
     for col in range(1, cols + 1):
        indices.append([row, col])
```

which returns:

```
<<<indices
[[1, 1], [1, 2], [1, 3], [2, 1], [2, 2], [2, 3]]
```

...but there has to be a cooler way (and, yeah, I know I can turn that into a list comprehension). Any ideas?

Comment: already answered https://stackoverflow.com/questions/533905/get-the-cartesian-product-of-a-series-of-lists

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`itertools.product`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/itertools.html#itertools.product):

```
from itertools import product

print(list(product(range(1, 3), range(1, 4))))
```

Prints:

```
[(1, 1), (1, 2), (1, 3), (2, 1), (2, 2), (2, 3)]
```